# Mocking data for a Context .Provider with Jest and React-Testing-Library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am working on testing a React/Typescript using Jest and RTL but having trouble structuring the data to pass in as a value to the `PostContext.Provider` component in my test. The test spits out that the `comment` value in the `commentBlock` component is undefined.

I expect the test to work but having trouble with how to best structure that data being passed to the provider in the test.

I am aware of the React-testing-library principles of modeling tests after the way your software is used and have read **[this](https://polvara.me/posts/mocking-context-with-react-testing-library)** post explaining how to test components using React Context.

Here is the test:

```
import React from 'react'
import { screen, render } from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import CommentBlock from '../components/postBlock/commentBlock'
import PostContext from '../../src/context/Post'

// jest.mock('../../src/context/Post')

// mocked props
const commentId = 'commentId'
const page = '/user'

function renderCommentBlock(data, commentId, page) {
    return render(
        <PostContext.Provider value={data}>
            <CommentBlock commentId={commentId} page={page} />
        </PostContext.Provider>
    )
}

test('should render CommentBlock correctly with props', () => {
    const comment = {
        commentsById: {
            commentId: 'string',
        },
    }

    renderCommentBlock(comment, commentId, page)
    screen.debug()
})
```

Component I am testing that uses `PostContext`:

```
// import BlockButton from './blockButton';
import { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import dateformat from 'dateformat'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite'

import UnirepContext from '../../context/Unirep'
import PostContext from '../../context/Post'

import { EXPLORER_URL } from '../../config'
import { Page, ButtonType } from '../../constants'
import BlockButton from './blockButton'
import MarkdownIt from 'markdown-it'

const markdown = new MarkdownIt({
    breaks: true,
    html: false,
    linkify: true,
})

type Props = {
    commentId: string
    page: Page
}

const CommentBlock = ({ commentId, page }: Props) => {
    const postContext = useContext(PostContext)
    const comment = postContext.commentsById[commentId]
    const commentHtml = markdown.render(comment.content)
    const unirepConfig = useContext(UnirepContext)
    const date = dateformat(new Date(comment.post_time), 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM TT')
    const history = useHistory()
    const [isEpkHovered, setEpkHovered] = useState<boolean>(false)

    const gotoPost = () => {
        if (page === Page.User) {
            history.push(`/post/${comment.post_id}`, { commentId: comment.id })
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="comment-block">
            <div className="block-header comment-block-header no-padding">
                <div className="info">
                    <span className="date">{date} |</span>
                    <span
                        className="user"
                        onMouseEnter={() => setEpkHovered(true)}
                        onMouseLeave={() => setEpkHovered(false)}
                    >
                        Post by {comment.epoch_key}{' '}
                        <img
                            src={require('../../../public/images/lighting.svg')}
                        />
                        {isEpkHovered ? (
                            <span className="show-off-rep">
                                {comment.reputation ===
                                unirepConfig.commentReputation
                                    ? `This person is very modest, showing off only ${unirepConfig.commentReputation} Rep.`
                                    : `This person is showing off ${comment.reputation} Rep.`}
                            </span>
                        ) : (
                            <span></span>
                        )}
                    </span>
                </div>
                <a
                    className="etherscan"
                    target="_blank"
                    href={`${EXPLORER_URL}/tx/${comment.id}`}
                >
                    <span>Etherscan</span>
                    <img
                        src={require('../../../public/images/etherscan.svg')}
                    />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div
                className="block-content no-padding-horizontal"
                onClick={gotoPost}
            >
                <div
                    style={{
                        maxHeight: page == Page.Home ? '300px' : undefined,
                        overflow: 'hidden',
                    }}
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                        __html: commentHtml,
                    }}
                />
            </div>
            <div className="block-buttons no-padding">
                <BlockButton
                    type={ButtonType.Boost}
                    count={comment.upvote}
                    data={comment}
                />
                <BlockButton
                    type={ButtonType.Squash}
                    count={comment.downvote}
                    data={comment}
                />
                <BlockButton type={ButtonType.Share} count={0} data={comment} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default observer(CommentBlock)
```

Code-Trace of the error:
[image: err]

Thank you in advance.

I would also be interested in how you would test this component if any of you have different opinions :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this object structure:

```
const postData = {
        commentsById: {
            commentId: { 
                content: 'string',
                post_time: '00',
            },
        },
    }
```